# Groovy string to HashMap cast

Tags: string, groovy, hashmap

As you know, we can simply obtain a string from a hash using the toString() method. So we get string similar to this:

```
[first:[one:1.1], second:2]
```

The question is, how can we cast this string to hash again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `Eval.me` [static method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html#me%28java.lang.String%29):

```
def map = Eval.me( '[first:[one:1.1], second:2]' )
assert map == [first:[one:1.1], second:2]
```

Comment: @user1560997 Beware of the possibility of code injection attacks if the input string comes in some way from an untrusted source (e.g. a user). In that case, if the input format is negotiable, i'd recommend using JSON and then something like [`JsonSlurper#parseText`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html#parseText%28java.lang.String%29) to parse it :)